# iOS: Custom Cell Properties with Code and IB do not appear together

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, interface-builder

CustomCell.h

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
//Properties created in Code, not via IB.
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *labelUsername;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *circle;

//Properties Created through IB by control+drag
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *labelFirstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *labelLastName;


@end
```

CustomCell.m

```
@implementation CustomCell
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier

{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        //Creating properties in code
        self.circle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 40.0f, 40.0f)];
        [self.circle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor];

        self.labelUsername = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 20, 200.0f, 50.0f)];
        self.labelUsername.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.labelUsername];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.circle];
    }
    return self;
}
```

tableView.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *customCellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:inviteCellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.labelFirstName.text = @"FirstName";
    cell.labelLastName.text = @"LastName";
    return cell;
}
```

The code above continued to show `labelUsername` and `circle`.  However, the properties created using the IB (`labelFirstName` and `labelLastName`) did not appear.

So in tableView.m in `viewDidLoad` I registered the Nib with the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell"
                                               bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
         forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
}
```

Now `labelFirstName` and `labelLastName` appear, but the properties created with code (`labelUsername` and `circle`) DO NOT appear.

How can I get all 4 properties to show?

Comment: Override `awakeFromNib` method in `CustomCell` and add your `addSubview:` code there

Comment: Why doesn't it work with init?

Comment: Well, I would suggest you, to log all the subviews in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method and see if all those views you added are there. While you add those subviews in initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier initializer, override layoutSubviews and give frame to the views there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in `CustomCell.m`,

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.circle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 40.0f, 40.0f)];
    [self.circle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor];

    self.labelUsername = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 20, 200.0f, 50.0f)];
    self.labelUsername.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [self.contentView addSubview:self.labelUsername];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.circle];
}
```

Comment: Pls see [more](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html) details

Answer (score 0):

Try this after  `self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];`

```
NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"yourNibName" owner:self options:NULL];
[self addSubview:[views lastObject]];
```